# SQLAlchemy order_by with hybrid_property.expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a problem with ordering by hybrid_property, I create expression like in documentation, but is not sorted with sqlalchemy_utils.functions.sort_query

```
@hybrid_property
def organization_name(self):
    if self.is_hq_group():
        return self.name
    elif self.is_campus_group():
        return None
    else:
        org_obj = (
            Group.query.filter(
                Group.type == GroupType.GREEK_ORGANIZATION,
            )
            .filter(Group.children.any(id=self.id))
            .first()
        )
        return org_obj.name

@organization_name.expression
def organization_name(cls):   
    return select([Group.name]). \
        where(Group.type == GroupType.GREEK_ORGANIZATION). \
        where(Group.children.any(id=cls.id)). \
        limit(1)
```

But the query comes not sorted, without an exception... Here are 2 tables (M2M relation)

```
class GroupChildren(db.Model):
    """
    Through table that links a parent and child group.
    """

    __tablename__ = "group_children"

    # Group relationship
    group_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("group.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), primary_key=True
    )
    child_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey("group.id", ondelete="CASCADE"),
        primary_key=True,
    )

    is_dashboard_linked = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
```

Main Table have a Many-to-many relation with them-self

```
class Group(BaseModel):
    """A group of users with a name/identity."""

    query_class = GroupQuery

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    name = db.Column(db.String(100))

    type = db.Column(ChoiceType(GroupType, impl=db.Integer()))

    # Deleting a parent or a child will not delete associated groups.
    children = db.relationship(
        "Group",
        secondary="group_children",
        backref=db.backref("parents", lazy="dynamic"),
        passive_deletes=True,
        lazy="dynamic",
        primaryjoin="Group.id == group_children.c.group_id",
        secondaryjoin="Group.id == group_children.c.child_id",
    )
```